# JSF 2.0 navigating on commandLink and commandButton doesn't work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm using JSF 2.0 and I have a problem with navigation after both commandLink and commandButton. I use following code:

```
<h:commandLink action="login?faces-redirect=true" 
    value="#{showElementBean.showElement()}"> Login </h:commandLink>  

<h:commandButton action="login?faces-redirect=true" value="Move to login.xhtml" />
```

These tags are inside a form, login is just an example. Result of clicking on rendered controls is always POST with refresh of a current page. What do I wrong?

**Edit:**
According to comments of BalusC I' adding real code fragment:

```
<h:commandLink actionListener="#{showElementBean.showElement(element)}" 
    value="View" > </h:commandLink>
```

I have a page with a list of elements and I want to add links that leads to element view page. Thus I need to pass this element to a show page. I'm JSF primer, e.g. in Rails I'd use GET and URL params, but I don't know how to do it 'in JSF-way'.

Comment: Do you have a <h:messages /> element on the page? Does it say anything.

Comment: I have it in the same form, but it shows nothing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a lot of possible causes for this behaviour. They are all cited in the following answer, along with solutions: [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked).

However, in your particular case, you seem rather to be interested in plain GET requests instead of POST requests, as all you want is simple page-to-page navigation. In that case, you need a `<h:link>` or `<h:button>` instead:

```
<h:link outcome="login" value="Login" />

<h:button outcome="login" value="Move to login.xhtml" />
```

*(I have no idea what you're trying to do with **both** `#{showElementBean.showElement()}` and `Login` as command link value, so I omitted the former)*

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)

Comment: Login is maybe not the best example. I have a list of items and I want to pass one of them to show item view. I think GET is sufficient, but I don't know how to pass params and read them before rendering show page. Btw. normal link and button works perfectly.

Comment: Use `<f:param>` in link/button and `<f:viewParam>` in target page. See also [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Processing GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters). By the way, you should really be certain whether it's supposed to be either GET (bookmarkable, searchbot-indexable) or POST (not bookmarkable/indexable). In your examples you were however not invoking any bean action methods, so I understood that you just want GET after all.

Comment: Thanks I added more detail to explain using POST/GET.

Comment: So you want to use GET and URL params? Then the `<f:param>` recommendation still applies.

Comment: Finally I used GET with solution described in your blog.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this info: **[JSF HTML Tags](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/index.jsf)**

> ### h:commandButton
>
> The commandButton tag renders an HTML submit button that can be
>   associated with a backing bean or ActionListener class for event
>   handling purposes. The display value of the button can also be
>   obtained from a message bundle to support internationalization (I18N).
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> <h:commandButton id="button1" value="#{bundle.checkoutLabel}" action="#{shoppingCartBean.checkout}" />
> ```
>
> **HTML Output**
>
> ```
> <input id="form:button1" name="form:button1" type="submit" value="Check Out" onclick="someEvent();" />
> ```
>
> ### h:commandLink
>
> The commandLink tag renders an HTML anchor tag that behaves like a
>   form submit button and that can be associated with a backing bean or
>   ActionListener class for event handling purposes. The display value of
>   the link can also be obtained from a message bundle to support
>   internationalization (I18N).
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> <h:commandLink id="link1" value="#{bundle.checkoutLabel}" action="#{shoppingCartBean.checkout}" />
> ```
>
> **HTML Output**
>
> ```
> <a href="#" onclick="someEvent();" id="form:link1">Check Out</a>
> ```

Comment: -1: You are not answering his concrete question at all and you were just copypasting from jsftoolbox.com website without citing the source.

Comment: @Balu: Nothing like that. Am trying to explain this so he might understand, what he is missing on his full code that which we haven't seen.

Comment: This is not an answer. You are not explaining why the OP is facing the particular problem. Just post a link to jsftoolbox.com as a comment on the question then.

Comment: Thanks Balu for your concern. Actually I thought, if I post the content then it may help him and others too. Ok then I will wait for some time, if any more downvotes are there and others too feeling this is not useful information then I will remove my post.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that backing bean method is not called if the form is for file upload: 
    `<h:form name="searchForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/search">`

Comment: Your problem is caused by something else than the OP's concrete problem. If you need help on it, just ask a new question instead of posting it as an irrelevant answer.

Comment: I saw the same behavior. If I add enctype as multipart, the backing bean is not called anymore. Not sure how I can fix it.

Answer (score -3):

I also faced with that issue and adding the 
    `<h:form><h:commandLink></h:commandLink> </h:form>`
solved my problem.

Comment: You're not answering the OP's concrete problem at all. OP clearly mentioned that he already has them in a form. In any case, Stack Overflow is not the right place for "Me too!" clutter like as on those old fashioned discussion forums which made those places a hard-to-search mess. Just upvote the helpful answer if you can and move on.