# Display not working with onselectMenu and file upload

Tags: primefaces

I encountered a problem on selectOneMenu component and the primefaces fileupload.

```
<h:outputLabel value="Categorie :"  />  
            <p:selectOneMenu  value="#{composantbean.selectedCategoryId}" required="true" >  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select categorie" itemValue="" />  
                <f:selectItems  value="#{composantbean.listcat}" var="cat" itemValue="#{cat.nomCat}" itemLabel="#{cat.nomCat}" /> 
                <p:ajax update="panlecart2"  event="change" listener="#{composantbean.catListener()}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

My problem is at the display.
the selectOneMenu is displayed but ItemLabel is hidden with a black color of my theme "trontastic"

[image]
and the file upload is not displayed.

This problem no longer exite when I work with explorer instead of chrome
or when I do

```
<p:commandButton value="Annuler" update="panel1" process="@this">
      <p:resetInput target="panel1" />
     </ p: commandButton>
```

[image]
I should do, please thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the root cause but here is a temporary solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document.getElementById('button')).click();
});
```

And this script execute your button:

```
<p:commandButton id="button"value="Annuler" update="panel1" process="@this" style="display:none;">
      <p:resetInput target="panel1" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Try to give exact client id of the button inside javascript function. You can detect it via browser's settings.

About problem's itself; `p:selectOneMenu` showing the selected value inside of a label. I guess sth. overrides it's css, let give an id to your `p:selectOneMenu`(let say menu) and if it is exists inside of a form(let's say it's id is form). So you can try to change the css of that label via:

```
$(document.getElementById('form:menu_label')).css("width":150);
```

Or directly alter the css class which is `.ui-selectonemenu label`

Also to be able to avoid from view state bug `ajax=false` should be added into navigation button. Actually navigation should be done via links and their `outcome` property like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225824/jsf-2-0-navigating-on-commandlink-and-commandbutton-doesnt-work).

Comment: the same page when I call it from anothor jsp page <body>
<% response.sendRedirect("login.jsf"); %>
</body> it works fine why

Comment: great that can be view state bug again. If you are coming this page via button you can add `ajax=false`.

Answer (score 1):

when I chnage my methode like this

```
public String Ajouter(){
    selcetitem=new Composant();
    return "AjoutC?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

instead of this

```
public String Ajouter(){
        selcetitem=new Composant();
        return "AjoutC";
    }
```

it works fine :)